# Evaluation of effectiveness of linear filtering on nonlinear processes

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, nonparametric, nonlinear-regression

I was across the following problem recently. I have a nonlinear bivariate process, where $X$ is causing $Y$, i.e.
$$
   y_i=f(x_i) + \varepsilon_i,
$$
where $f$ is a nonlinear function. To evaluate the dependence between $X$ and $Y$ I use a nonparametric test, for instance entropy test of pairwise independence as described in Maasoumi and Racine (2002). I get the p-value of say 0.01, suggesting that there is indeed dependence between the variables.

Now, I would like to test how efficient linear filtering is. To do that, I first run a simple OLS model on the variables and I perform the test between residuals and the independent variable. Let's say that the new p-value is 0.1, so that linear filtering was successful in decreasing the dependence between $X$ and $Y$.

How I can measure the effectiveness of this linear filtering? Do you know any already-developed approaches? Can I compare the two p-values directly? Or maybe a function of them? Is it possible to relate this effectiveness in terms of statistical significance?